# How to fetch data from this kind of web service

Tags: android, json

This is my web service data.

```
[
    {
        "msgid": "1",
        "title": "Lorem Ipsum is simply text",
        "dt": "05-SEP-2012"
    },
    {
        "msgid": "2",
        "title": "Lorem Ipsum is simply ",
        "dt": "16-NOV-2011"
    },
    {
        "msgid": "3",
        "title": "Lorem Ipsum is simply text",
        "dt": "13-SEP-2012"
    },
    {
        "msgid": "4",
        "title": "Lorem Ipsum is simply text2",
        "dt": "26-SEP-2012"
    },
    {
        "msgid": "5",
        "title": "Lorem Ipsum is simply text",
        "dt": "30-SEP-2012"
    },
    {
        "msgid": "6",
        "title": "test message ",
        "dt": "12-OCT-2012"
    },
    {
        "msgid": "7",
        "title": "test message ",
        "dt": "01-OCT-2012"
    }
]
```

How can I fetch this data to app in Android using JSON parsing?
what is the java code for this data can u help me....plz....

Comment: Could you tell us what you have tried till now? Have you been able to make the Network call to get the above data? Or are you having trouble parsing the JSON data?

Comment: I am trying to fetch this data and display on my application screen,but can u please till me how to do..using json

Comment: what is the java code for fetching this kind of data from website using json parsing.....can u help me...plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public class Original_list extends Activity {

```
 TextView web;
 ArrayList<String>  id1,question1 ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);
 web = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.web1);
 id1 = new ArrayList<String>();
 question1= new ArrayList<String>();
try {
    JSONArray jary = new JSONArray(readTxt());
    for(int i = 0 ;i<=jary.length();i++)
    {
        JSONObject jread = jary.getJSONObject(i);
        String   id = jread.getString("question");
        Log.d("value of id", ""+id);
        id1.add(id);
        String name = jread.getString("answer");
        Log.d("value of id", ""+id);
        question1.add(name);
        Log.e("id","question is"+id);
      Log.e("id","question is"+name);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}   
 web.setText(""+id1+""+question1);
    web.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
}

private String readTxt(){

         InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.details);

         ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

         int i;
      try {
       i = inputStream.read();
       System.out.println("what"+i);
       while (i != -1)
          {
           byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
           i = inputStream.read();
           System.out.println("what_next"+i);
          }
          inputStream.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
      }

         return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
        }
```

}

Comment: but,in that not pass uri String

Comment: think budy.....it really help me.....

Comment: At least one thumbs up dude